Running 2 authority collators but they are not peering
two nodes are running in the same machine but not peering. Someone give some advice?
1st Authority:
./target/release/parachain-template-node 
-lbasic-authorship=trace 
--bob 
--collator 
--force-authoring 
--chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json 
--base-path ./tmp/node02 
--port 40334 
--rpc-port 8845 
-- 
--execution wasm 
--chain paseo.json 
--port 30344 
--rpc-port 9978 
--rpc-methods unsafe 
--unsafe-rpc-external 
--blocks-pruning=256
2nd Authority:
./target/release/parachain-template-node 
-lbasic-authorship=trace 
--alice 
--collator 
--force-authoring 
--chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json 
--base-path ./tmp/node01 
--port 40333 
--rpc-port 8844 
-- 
--execution wasm 
--chain paseo.json 
--port 30343 
--rpc-port 9977 
--rpc-methods unsafe 
--unsafe-rpc-external 
--bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/40334/p2p/12D3KooWEJEhoow5F88C6FbukJ3soTz5DtXG4sG5qxMHQZE1wsk4 
--blocks-pruning=256
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air polkadot-runtime-template % ./target/release/parachain-template-node 
-lbasic-authorship=trace 
--bob 
--collator 
--force-authoring 
--chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json 
--base-path ./tmp/node02 
--port 40334 
--rpc-port 8845 
-- 
--execution wasm 
--chain paseo.json 
--port 30344 
--rpc-port 9978 
--rpc-methods unsafe 
--unsafe-rpc-external 
--blocks-pruning=256
Output of node01:
2024-04-09 18:26:19.600  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Parachain Collator Template    
2024-04-09 18:26:19.600  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.1.2-3cf723be055    
2024-04-09 18:26:19.600  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by OpenZeppelin, 2020-2024    
2024-04-09 18:26:19.600  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Live Xcavate Testnet    
2024-04-09 18:26:19.600  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: Bob    
2024-04-09 18:26:19.600  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2024-04-09 18:26:19.600  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: RocksDb at ./tmp/node02/chains/live_xcavate_testnet/db/full    
CLI parameter `--execution` has no effect anymore and will be removed in the future!
2024-04-09 18:26:20.801  WARN main sc_cli::commands::run_cmd: It isn't safe to expose RPC publicly without a proxy server that filters available set of RPC methods.    
2024-04-09 18:26:20.801  INFO main parachain_template_node::command: Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPKvnFY6pptWxiSRJXVtNgxy6ymX5caA6LjuGtCbUxo    
2024-04-09 18:26:20.802  INFO main parachain_template_node::command: Is collating: yes    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.915  INFO main sub-libp2p: [Relaychain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWKuyUJ2jZqC2DnZxrkCWTvcDM4epuzVBtCDKhrsuph2ei    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.921  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Operating system: macos    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.921  INFO main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  CPU architecture: aarch64    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.921  INFO main sc_service::builder: [Relaychain]  Highest known block at #705112    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.921  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate_prometheus_endpoint: [Relaychain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9616    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.924  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: [Relaychain] Running JSON-RPC server: addr=0.0.0.0:9978, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.924  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  CPU score: 611.38 MiBs    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.924  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Memory score: 27.25 GiBs    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.924  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Disk score (seq. writes): 1.84 GiBs    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.924  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Relaychain]  Disk score (rand. writes): 305.94 MiBs    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.932  INFO                 main sub-libp2p: [Parachain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWEJEhoow5F88C6FbukJ3soTz5DtXG4sG5qxMHQZE1wsk4    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.937  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Parachain]  Operating system: macos    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.937  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo: [Parachain]  CPU architecture: aarch64    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.937  INFO                 main sc_service::builder: [Parachain]  Highest known block at #5638    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.938  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate_prometheus_endpoint: [Parachain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2024-04-09 18:26:26.938  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: [Parachain] 


I'm not sure, but it might be related to OS problems.
Occasionally, when running several nodes on one computer, the DHT auto-discovery fails to operate correctly. Consider manually setting a bootnode.
By the way, in your command, you've provided the parachain bootnode URI to the  relaychain's bootnode flag. Put it before the --.
